# Android:How to change the logo of Up navigation in Actionlayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The logo at left in the original ActionBar is not the app icon.
An ActionLayout is added to a button.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"/>
```

But in case of this button is clicked, the ActionBar is changed, and also the logo at left, which is the app icon in Up navigation.
How to make the logo not changed?

Answer (score 0):

Through styles.xml with the following items

```
 <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/home_up_drawable</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/home_up_drawable</item>
  </style>
```

At runtime with `setIcon()` . For instance:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setIcon();
```

`setIcon` takes the id `of` the a resource or a `drawable`.

You can set also `android:logo` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but maybe you misunderstood the question.I show you a pic of the ActionBar [link]http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/mw690/3c6ca901tw1e6xz0d8935j20ld080js3.jpg